# A reflective subcategory of the category of inverse semigroups.

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, semigroups, inverse-semigroups

### The Question.

I'm reading Lawson's [*"Inverse Semigroups: The Theory of Partial Symmetries"*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Inverse-Semigroups-Theory-Partial-Symmetries/dp/9810233167) and I've hit something I don't understand. It's claimed on page 34 of my copy that

> The category of complete, infinitely distributive inverse semigroups together with join-preserving homomorphisms forms a subcategory of the category of inverse semigroups and homomorphisms; indeed, the former is a *reflective subcategory* of the latter.

Let's call them $\mathbf{CompInfDist}_{\vee}$ and $\mathbf{InvSem}$, respectively.

> What exactly is the left adjoint of the inclusion functor that makes $\mathbf{CompInfDist}_{\vee}$ reflective in $\mathbf{InvSem}$?

### The Details.

This is technical stuff so let's have some definitions. Let $S$ be an inverse semigroup. Following Lawson . . .

> **Definition 1:** The *compatibility relation* on $S$ is given by $$s\sim t\iff st^{-1}, s^{-1}t\in E(S),$$ where $E(S)$ is the set of idempotents of $S$.
>
> **Definition 2:** A subset $A$ of $S$ is *compatible* if any pair of elements in $A$ are compatible.

The meet, $a\wedge b$, on $S$ for $a, b\in S$ is defined as the greatest lower bound of $a$ and $b$ with respect to the natural order on $S$; the join ($\vee$) is given dually. These extend to sets naturally.

> **Definition 3:** We say $S$ is *complete* if every non-empty compatible subset of $S$ has a join.
>
> **Definition 4:** We say $S$ is *left infinitely distributive* if, whenever $A$ is a non-empty subset of $S$ for which $\bigvee A$ exists, then $\bigvee sA$ exists for any element $s\in S$ and $s\left(\bigvee A\right)=\bigvee sA$. Then $S$ is *infinitely distributive* if it is both left and right infinitely distributive, where "right infinitely distributive" is defined analogously to left.

Now quoting MacLane,

> **Definition 5:** A subcategory $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal B$ is called *reflective* ($*$) in $\mathcal B$ when the inclusion functor $K:\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ has a left adjoint $F:\mathcal B\to\mathcal A$.

### My Attempt.

I'm completely at a loss. I'm sorry. I've written out **all** the relevant definitions on my whiteboard, including peripheral, easy ones like "functor", "adjoint", "subcategory", etc., but I just don't see it.

Anyway, thank you for reading all of this!

Please help :)

---

I've had an idea!

> **Definition 6:** A subset $A$ of $S$ is *permissible* if it is a compatible order ideal. The set of all permissible subsets of $S$ is denoted $C(S)$.
>
> **Lemma 1:** $C(S)$ (under multiplication of subsets) is an object of $\mathbf{CompInfDist}_{\vee}$.

*"Proof":* This is Theorem 1.4.23 of Lawson's book. $\square$

$\color{red}{\text{Perhaps}}$

[image],

where $F=C'$ is given by $C'(S\stackrel{f}{\to}T)=C(S)\stackrel{Cf}{\longrightarrow}C(T)$ for $Cf: C(S)\to C(T)$ given by $A\mapsto f(A)$. But this needs to satisfy $$\hom_{\mathbf{CompInfDist}_{\vee}}(C(S), Q)\cong_{\varphi_{(S, Q)}}\hom_{\mathbf{InvSem}}(S, K(Q)=Q)$$ for some natural bijection $\varphi_{(S, Q)}$.

---

Define $\iota: S\to C(S)$ by $\iota(s)=[s]$, where $[s]$ is the $\sim$-class of $s$.

> **Lemma 2:** If $\theta: S\to Q$ is a homomorphism to an object $Q$ in $\mathbf{CompInfDist}_{\vee}$ then there exists a unique morphism $\theta^*:C(S)\to Q$ in $\mathbf{CompInfDist}_{\vee}$ given by $$\theta^*(A)=\bigvee\{\theta(a)\mid a\in A\}$$ such that $\theta^*\iota=\theta$.

*"Proof":* This is Theorem 1.4.24 of Lawson's book.$\square$

$\color{red}{\text{Maybe}}\,\varphi^{-1}_{(S, Q)}(\theta)=\theta^*$. But what's $\varphi_{(S, Q)}$ given by?

I'm not sure of the details :/

---

($*$) See the comments: I think this is the definition Lawson intended.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I see the subcategory bit now; that's easy. Forget about the join-preservation.

Comment: According to Theorem 16.8 in Adamek-Herrlich-Strecker, if there is some factorization structure on a category (and fulfills some additional conditions), the epireflective subcategories are precisely the subcategories closed under (extremal) subobjects and products. I am not familiar with semigroups, but perhaps you are able to say whether your subcategory is closed under products, and extremal subobjects.

Comment: Mac Lane is not totally standard here. Usually reflective subcategories are assumed to be full. Otherwise, the concept is not very useful. For example, you wouldn't call $\mathbf {Semigroups}\subseteq\mathbf {Monoids} $ full, whereas $\mathbf {Monoids}\subseteq\mathbf {Groups} $ is reflective.

Comment: Typo, of course I meant that Semigroups is not reflective in Monoids.

Comment: @JakobWerner Thank you for the clarification. I suppose I should mention, then, that Lawson gave a reference to MacLane in the paragraph of the page-34 quote of mine above. Perhaps the non-standard definition was intended :)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Although your suggestion doesn't help me (at least) with this question (at the moment), it looks like it will be very useful for me in the near future. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is absolutely right. The map $\varphi_{(S,Q)}$ maps a morphism $\psi \colon C(S) \rightarrow Q$ (in $\mathrm{CompInfDist}_\vee$) to the morphism $\psi \circ \iota_S$ (in $\mathrm{InvSem}$), where $\iota_S \colon S \hookrightarrow C(S)$ is the map you denoted as $\iota$.

Comment: (+1) That's been on the tip of my tongue for days now! **Thank you!** I upvoted this answer late last night but wanted to check it first before accepting. (Yes, it's correct! :D)